# Easy way to share files between Linux desktop and Windows remote desktop?

Tags: windows, linux, remote-desktop, rdesktop

Is there a way to have drag and drop access between Linux and a Windows Remote Desktop connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rdesktop` supports a remotedisk option which will make a share appear within the Windows computer that you have opened a remote desktop connection to.

For example:

```
-r disk:remotedisk=/home/kbrandt/Desktop/Shared
```

It will show up on the Windows box as "remoted on *hostname*":

[image]